# Including submodule .xcdatamodeld file in project

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am currently building multiple applications that all share the same CoreData stack. This includes models, network requests, etc. Basically all of the business logic is held in this repository (let's call it DataKit). The DataKit project generates a static library called DataKit.a

Now I have two apps, App A and App B. Both of them need to include the .xcdatamodeld in DataKit. How I have done this in the past, is to copy the .xcdatamodeld file from DataKit and put it into the App A or App B project. This is really ugly and I am trying to figure out a cleaner way to include the .xcdatamodeld file without having to copy it into the App project.

I've tried adding the .xcdatamodeld file to a Copy Files phase in the Build Phases for DataModel.a but it didn't work.

Anyone have any suggestions/tips?

Answer (score 3):

The `.xcdatamodeld` file is an abstract representation of the managed object model that is *compiled* into a `.momd` file. The `.momd` file is what Core Data opens. For your projects, you would need to either have the `.xcdatamodeld` in the Compile Sources phase, or the `.momd` file in the Copy Files phase of the target that is *dependent on* the library. Obviously, this is pretty cumbersome when attempting to distribute code as a library. Frameworks allow you to include resources (such as `momd` files), and are in general much more flexible than libraries. iOS 8 allows dynamic frameworks, [previous versions of iOS allow static frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25150220/1059025) even if the tools do not exactly support it.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that about iOS 8 and dynamic frameworks. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could include a method in your framework that returns the correct data model. It is not necessary to be stored in the bundle as a separate file / directory.

Comment: 1. He is building a static library, not a framework. 2. Returning the model from a method does not help with his problem, as he can't include the model to be loaded at all.